# Application version => or Like

Tags: azure, kql

I have to check an application version
I'd like to mark as compliant if the version is => of 116.x.x.x

This i s my query

AppInventory_CL
| where AppName_s in ('Microsoft Edge') or '*' in ('Microsoft Edge')
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ManagedDeviceID_g, AppName_s, AppPublisher_s
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s
| extend Versione = iif(AppVersion_s >= '116.0.0.0','OK','KO')

But I have this error

Cannot compare values of types string and string. Try adding explicit casts

Any help?

Thanks

This i s my query

AppInventory_CL
| where AppName_s in ('Microsoft Edge') or '*' in ('Microsoft Edge')
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ManagedDeviceID_g, AppName_s, AppPublisher_s
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s
| extend Versione = iif(AppVersion_s >= '116.0.0.0','OK','KO')

But I have this error

Cannot compare values of types string and string. Try adding explicit casts

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use mathematical things on strings, and version numbers don't always instantly translate to "proper" numbers.  You'll probably want to [`split`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/splitfunction) up the version number and do some numerical checking that way.

```
AppInventory_CL 
| where AppName_s in ('Microsoft Edge') or '*' in ('Microsoft Edge') 
| summarize arg_max(TimeGenerated, *) by ManagedDeviceID_g, AppName_s, AppPublisher_s 
| project ComputerName_s, AppName_s, AppVersion_s 
| extend AppVersion_s_Dyn = split(AppVersion_s, '.') //Split the version
| extend Versione = iif(toint(AppVersion_s_Dyn[0]) >= 116 and toint(AppVersion_s_Dyn[-1]) > 0, 'OK', 'KO') //Check on the individual elements
//| summarize count() by Versione //Generate what we want on the pie chart
//| render piechart //Show the piechart
```

Comment: Great! It works thanks!